# make df from matching columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2 having columns as `df1['date','customer_id','category_name']` and `df2['date','customer_id','category_name']`. I want values from df1 which matches in df2 on columns 'customer_id' & 'category_name'.

So I tried this:

```
df_final = df1[(df1['customer_id']==df2['customer_id'])&(df1['category_name']==df2['category_name'])]
```

but it is showing 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects' dataframes
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `merge`

```
df_final = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["customer_id", "category_name"], how="left")
```